# Symmetric and transitive custom unit conversion in Perl

Tags: perl, unit-conversion

I've defined the following custom units (psuedo-code):

```
unix_days = unix_seconds/86400; 
nasa_seconds = unix_seconds - 946728000;
```

This lets me directly convert `unix_seconds` to `unix_days` or convert 
`unix_seconds` to `nasa_seconds`.

However, I can't directly convert `unix_days` back to `unix_seconds` 
without writing another formula.

Similarly, I can't convert `nasa_seconds` to `unix_days` without writing 
additional formulas.

Is there a clever Perl subroutine or package that lets me do this 
without writing additional functions? More specifically, a custom unit 
conversion package that:

- Can divine the inverse of a unit conversion function. For example, 
  the opposite of `f(x)=x/86400` is `g(y)=y*86400`.
- Can apply transitivity as needed. For example, if `unix_seconds = nasa_seconds + 946728000` (by functional inverse) and `unix_days = unix_seconds/86400`, we can combine these to convert directly from `nasa_seconds` to `unix_days`.

I'm OK with writing my conversion formulas in unusual ways if 
needed. For example, Celsius to Fahrenheit could be written as:

```
C to F: *1.8 +32
```

This form is easy to invert: just follow the steps backwards and in 
reverse, namely:

```
F to C: -32 /1.8
```

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Physics::Unit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Physics::Unit) should provide the facilities that you require.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't realize there were packages like that, which let you define your own units.